# Counting different occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am studying SQL using PostreSQL and I have a doubt regarding counting the number of different occurrences of a column's values with respect to another.

I suppose this is not the typical `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` problem because I cannot find any help or reference for my problem, so I will better explain what I would like to do (if possible) with a short example.
Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    genre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MOVIE PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, 'Horror', 'EEUU');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, 'Drama', 'EEEU');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (3, 'Drama', 'Italy');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (4, 'Horror', 'UK');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (5, 'Drama', 'EEEU');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (6, 'Drama', 'EEEU');
```

So `MYTABLE` looks like this:

```
 id | genre  | country 
----+--------+---------
  1 | Horror | EEUU
  2 | Drama  | EEEU
  3 | Drama  | Italy
  4 | Horror | UK
  5 | Drama  | EEEU
  6 | Drama  | EEEU
```

I can now count how many times the value of `country` is repeated for each value of `genre` with the following query:

```
select distinct count(*), m.genre, m.country
FROM MYTABLE m
GROUP BY m.genre, m.country;
```

which returns:

```
 count | genre  | country 
-------+--------+---------
     3 | Drama  | EEEU
     1 | Horror | EEUU
     1 | Horror | UK
     1 | Drama  | Italy
(4 rows)
```

But how could I obtain how many different values of `country` I have for each `genre` ? In other words I would like to obtain such a table:

```
 genre  | different_countries 
--------+------------------
 Horror |       2
 Drama  |       2
```

Does exist such a query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `count(distinct)`:

```
select m.genre, count(distinct m.country)
from MYTABLE m
group by m.genre;
```

As for your query, you almost never need to use `select distinct` with `group by` -- and not in this `case`.  `group by` already removes duplicate rows for the `group by` keys.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use `subquery`

```
select count(1), t1.genre from (
  select distinct country, genre
  from MOVIE) as t1
group by t1.genre
```